# Python: 'Waiting for player...' cancel button doesn't work while listening for connection. Window freezes

Tags: python, sockets, bind, listen

Have a very simple tic-tac-toe game that uses a P2P architecture. When a player presses the 'create' button a window pops up with a label that says 'Waiting for player...' and a button to cancel. It then creates a socket, binds, listens, and then waits to accept. Once a connection is accepted it closes that window and a game window opens.

The join button connects to the 'server' and a game window opens.
Everything works but the cancel button.
The 'cancel' button calls a function to close the socket, and then destroy the window.

The issue is the window freezes when the socket is listening for a connection and so the user can't click the cancel button. How would I go about implementing such feature?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are doing GUI programming, the socket thing should always be handled in other thread, instead of the main thread.